# Only use functions of .ksh script into other script

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a script `a.sh` which has :

```
a() {
     echo "123"
  }

 echo "dont"
```

Then I have other script `b.sh` which has :

```
 b() {
       echo "345"
 }
```

All I want to do is to use `a` in `b`, but when I source it I don't want to print whatever is in `a()` or `echo "Dont"`.

I just want to source it for now.

so I did, source `a.sh` in `b.sh`

But it doesn't work.

Reason for sourcing is. so if I want I can call any functions when I want too.

If I do `. /a.sh` in `b.sh` it prints everything in `a.sh`.

Comment: Can you do `. /a.sh > /dev/null`?

Comment: In bash, you could check this by looking at the value of `${#BASH_SOURCE[@]}`. Not sure about ksh -- and ksh versions differ quite a bit from each other. Could you specify which you're using?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - do you mean ${#BASH_SOURCE[a.sh]}  ???

usr/bin/ksh

Comment: Put `a()` in a file on its own and source it into both.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - can you Please give an example of what you mean by source it into both

Comment: Sure, see my answer below.

Comment: @kyle, no, I don't mean that. I meant exactly what I typed.

Comment: ...what that does in bash is retrieve the length of the `BASH_SOURCE` array, which will be of size 1 if you're being directly invoked from the top level of a script, or a larger value if being sourced in or called from a function.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh this is in .ksh

Comment: @kyle, I know -- that's why this is a comment, not an answer, and why I explicitly said "in bash" in all of those comments. It's also why I asked you exactly which version of ksh you were running.

Comment: yea. Sorry, I am trying to learn .ksh thats why I am just using ksh

Comment: "just using ksh"? There are many, **many** different versions of ksh. "Just using ksh" in no way tells us anything useful about which one. pdksh? ksh93? ksh88? mksh? ...

Comment: i did which ksh on my terminal , it showed /usr/bin/ksh

Comment: @kyle, ...which is to say you don't know which version you have installed as `/usr/bin/ksh`? That's not particularly useful if you want a ksh-specific answer, as opposed to a generic POSIX one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a library of common functions in a file called `functionLib.sh` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

a(){
   echo Inside a, with $1
}

b(){
   echo Inside b, with $1
}
```

Then in `script1`, do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
. functionLib.sh    # Source in the functions

a 42                # Use one
b 37                # Use another
```

and in another script, `script2` re-use the functions:

```
#!/bin/sh
. functionLib.sh    # Source in the functions

a 23                # Re-use one
b 24                # Re-use another
```

Comment: It will work, make your other script that uses `a()` also just `dot in` functionLib.sh just like the second line of my second example code.

Comment: Just for understanding, so you are running another script, that is calling functionlib.sh and using a 42, it is printing whatevr is in a() correct?

Comment: I am putting one, or more, functions that are used by multiple scripts, all in one place, one file, so there is less maintenance and more consistency amongst all the scripts that want to use them.

Comment: oh. so if I have a third file. 
which has 

     b 43

how can i use that output in the function that you wrote. now I think $1 will clash for both

Comment: No, $1 is the parameter that the function was called with - each function has its own parameters.

Answer (score 2):

One approach which will work on any POSIX-compliant shell is this:

```
# put function definitions at the top
a() {
     echo "123"
}

# divide them with a conditional return
[ -n "$FUNCTIONS_ONLY" ] && return

# put direct code to execute below
echo "dont"
```

...and in your other script:

```
 FUNCTIONS_ONLY=1 . other.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

I have adopted a style in my shell scripts that allows me to design every script as a potential library, making it behave differently when it is sourced (with `. .../path/script`) and when it is executed directly.   You can compare this to the python `if __name__ == '__main__':` trick.

I have not found a method that is portable across all Bourne shell descendants without explicitly referring to the script's name, but this is what I use:

```sh
a() {
    echo a
}

b() {
    echo b
}


(program=xyzzy
  set -u -e   
  case $0 in
  *${program}) : ;;
  *) exit;;
  esac

  # main
  a
  b
)
```

The rules for this method are strictly:

1. Start a section with nothing but functions.
   No variable assignments or any other activity.
2. Then, at the very end, create a subshell `(` ... `)`
3. The first action inside the subshell tests whether
   it's being sourced.  If so, exit from the subshell.
   If not, run a command.

Comment: If you wanted to avoid the subshell overhead, you could use `return` rather than `exit` -- though of course this means you'd want to move the side-effecting parts of your preamble after / below the test.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I fear that using `return` might not work with all shells.  I tested the above with ksh93, bash and `/bin/sh` on ubuntu (which I think is actually dash).

Comment: @HenkLangeveld, the behavior in question is explicitly specified by POSIX; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_24

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Granted, though I've worked with *really* *old* shells that would not support that behaviour.  I actually *prefer* to work with the superset of features supported by bash and ksh93.

Comment: Sure -- pre-POSIX Bourne is its own animal, but the only (modernish) place that's found is oldish Solaris. You'll have no trouble using POSIX features in ksh93, bash or dash, though, and those are the three you mention testing against.